# Sklearn and PCA. Why is max n_row == max n_components?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, pca

I have a high-dimensional word-bi-gram frequency matrix (1100 x 100658, dtype=int). As column-names I'm setting the word-bi-grams (like 'of-the', 'and-the',...) with 
myPandaDataFrame.columns = word-bi-grams 
as row index I use for example the proficiency (high, medium, low)
myPandaDataFrame.columns.set_index(['PROFICIENCY'], inplace=True, drop=True)

then I'm doing

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
x = 500
pcax = PCA(n_components=x)
pcax.fit(myPandaDataFrame)
PCA(copy=True, n_components=x, whiten=False)
existing_2dx = pcax.transform(myPandaDataFrame)
existing_df_2dx = pandas.DataFrame(existing_2dx)
existing_df_2dx.index = myPandaDataFrame.index
existing_df_2dx.columns = ['PC{0}'.format(i) for i in range(x)]
```

My first problem, where I think it is wrong, is that I can set only a max number of 1100 components. That is the number of existing rows. I'm very new to PCA and tried couple of examples, but seems like I can't get it right for my matrix. 
Is someone seeing where I'm doing a mistake or can someone link to a tutorial / example which is similar to my problem. I would be very happy :)

With best regards

Comment: You might be able to get more help in http://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks, I will try that.

Comment: did any of the answers help?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have more components than the number of the dimensions (rank) of the space your matrix spans, which in turn would be no larger than the minimum of the number of rows or columns (or less if matrix is not of full rank).

See the below example: with a matrix of size `500 x 10000`, you can ask for 1,000 components and will get back 500, on which you can then project your matrix, returning a `500 x 500` matrix:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.random(size=(500, 10000)))

RangeIndex: 500 entries, 0 to 499
Columns: 10000 entries, 0 to 9999
dtypes: float64(10000)
memory usage: 38.1 MB

x = 1000
pca = PCA(n_components=x)
pca.fit(df)
pca.explained_variance_ratio_.shape

(500,)

existing_2dx = pca.transform(df)
existing_2dx.shape

(500, 500)
```

Answer (score 0):

PCA decomposes the empirical data covariance matrix into eigenvalues and vectors. This matrix has rank `min(n_lines, n_columns)`. After this number the eigenvalues become 0, so your data are entirely explained by the number of components up to there. This number of components reflects your data perfectly. In order to do any sort of dimensionality reduction you need to choose less components.